# How do whitespace tokens with '\n' affect spaCy's CNN?

Tags: spacy

spaCy's POS tagger produces different tags when there are whitespace tokens with linebreaks '\n' (but not for whitespace tokens containing only spaces):

```
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en')    
>>> text = 'The library respects your time, and tries to avoid wasting it.'
>>> text_with_ws = '   '.join(text.split())
>>> text_with_lb = '\n'.join(text.split())
>>> doc = nlp(text)
>>> print([t.pos_ for t in doc])
['DET', 'NOUN', 'VERB', 'ADJ', 'NOUN', 'PUNCT', 'CCONJ', 'VERB', 'PART', 'VERB', 'VERB', 'PRON', 'PUNCT']
>>> doc = nlp(text_with_ws)
>>> print([t.pos_ for t in doc if t.pos_ is not 'SPACE'])
['DET', 'NOUN', 'VERB', 'ADJ', 'NOUN', 'PUNCT', 'CCONJ', 'VERB', 'PART', 'VERB', 'VERB', 'PRON', 'PUNCT']
>>> doc = nlp(text_with_lb)
>>> print([t.pos_ for t in doc if t.pos_ is not 'SPACE'])
['DET', 'NOUN', 'NOUN', 'ADJ', 'NOUN', 'PUNCT', 'CCONJ', 'NOUN', 'PART', 'NOUN', 'NOUN', 'PRON', 'PUNCT']
```

Now, I do not understand how spacy's convolutional neural network works, but are different results to be expected?

Answer (score 1):

This is because newline causes a sentence segmentation where as spaces do not, spaces or tabs do not act as sentence delimiters.
This displacy output would show the difference between both parsings:
1. In `text_with_ws` example, the whole text is treated as one sentence, and hence dependency parsing & POS tagging works that way.
[image]

2. In `text_with_lb` example, each token is treated independently. ( have added `period (.)` instead of newline since displacy doesn't support newlines, period also acts as sentence delimiter just like newline)
   [image]

Comment: If line-breaks cause sentence segmentation, shouldn't this be reflected in `doc.sents`? I get:
```
    >>> text = 'The library respects your time, and tries to avoid wasting it.'
    >>> text_with_ws = '   '.join(text.split())
    >>> text_with_lb = '\n'.join(text.split())
    >>> text_with_punct = '. '.join(text.split())
    >>> len([s for s in nlp(text).sents])
    1
    >>> len([s for s in nlp(text_with_ws).sents])
    1
    >>> len([s for s in nlp(text_with_lb).sents])
    1
    >>> len([s for s in nlp(text_with_punct).sents])
    6
```